# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'tabsClick' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, typeerror

I have this strange error, I can't access the public method from my plugin. What is wrong here? I use jQuery 1.10.2.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'tabsClick' of undefined
```

Here is my plugin:

```
;(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.smk_Toolkit_Tabs = function( options ) {

        // Defaults
        var settings = $.extend({
            something: '.my_class',
        }, options );

        // Reffer to current instance
        var plugin = this;

        //"Constructor"
        var init = function() {
            //...
        }

        // My public method
        this.tabsClick = function() {
            //...
        }

        //"Constructor" init
        init();

    }

}( jQuery ));
```

Here is how I try to access the public method:

```
var tkp = $('.smk_toolkit_plugin_container').smk_Toolkit_Tabs();
tkp.tabsClick();
```

Comment: My guess is that `init` does not return anything, therefore `tkp` is `undefined`.

Comment: you should `retun this;` before the closing brace;

Comment: you need to look at some plugin development models

Comment: Arun P Johny, this is just an example. And is totally unrelevant to what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `return this;` before the end of `$.fn.smk_Toolkit_Tabs`.